# Handling exceptions in C#

Tags: c#

I have multiple methods that take some input and throw exceptions on failure. Only one or none of the methods can succeed with the same input.
Simple example:
`Result Calculate1(string input) { /*implmentation*/ }`
`Result Calculate2(string input) { /*implmentation*/ }`
`Result Calculate3(string input) { /*implmentation*/ }`

What I want to do is figure out which method will succeed without throwing an exception. Something like this:

```
Result Check(string input)
{
   try{
      return Calculate1(input);
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
      try{
         return Calculate2(input);
      }
      catch(Exception)
      {
         try{
            return Calculate3(input);
         }
         catch(Exception)
         {
            etc..
         }
      }

   }
}
```

This looks horrible though. Is there any way to make this cleaner?

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 3):

As long as your methods all have the same signature, you can just iterate over them:

```
var myMethods = new Func<string, Result>[] { Calculate1, Calculate2, Calculate3 };

foreach (var method in myMethods)
{
    try
    {
        return method(input);
    }
    // You should really check for a more specific exception here
    catch (Exception) { }
}

// All methods threw an exception
etc.
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o8KSq0) (using `int` as `Result` for simplicity)

Comment: the catch could be "simplified" to just `catch {}`

Comment: @RufusL: True. But catching `Exception` instead of `TheSpecificExceptionIExpect` is bad practice (with the exception of a top-level generic exception handler, but you need the exception variable there), so I don't really want to encourage that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be using exception handling for this. Instead, consider examining the properties of the string argument that is passed into your method to determine the right subroutine to engage.
For instance, you could use an if/else if/else structure to fall through different conditions. I don't know your criteria or possible conditions of the inbound string, so just consider this an example using easy tests:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) 
{
    //do some stuff
}
else if (input.Length < 10)
{
    // do something different
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

To figure out your conditionals, think about what exceptions you're anticipating and then write some tests to determine if the string meets those criteria or not. This could involve regular expressions or testing basic properties of the value as shown in the example above.
There are multiple ways to implement this approach, but the block above is a good starting point to illustrate a better approach.
In short, save the exception handling for unanticipated/untestable errors. Do as much as you can in code to avoid engaging exception handling - it's expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Your question opens up a lot of different approaches. The question is how to identify which calculation succeeded, without throwing exceptions. You should avoid to just throw exceptions to reroute your program logic, as exception throwing is expensive and slow.

How about using Tasks here, as they support cancellations and also fine grained control using task continuation or return as soon as possible using WhenAny for example ?

You might consider using tasks and the WhenAny method, which will give you the first calculation that succeeds. There are more considerations into this, such as passing in a CancellationToken into these calculations, so you can cancel the other tasks in case one calculation has finished. This will then as soon as possible cancel the tasks that don't need to finish as the first calculation has the result.

The following sample codes shows some aspects of this. We have three calculations and pass in a cancellation token. Note that we catch OperationCanceledException here inside the calculations. I know that Calculate3 will win, because it finishes first, so no OperationCanceledException is catched in that method. When running the Task.WhenAny method you can get an AggregateException which must be catched.

```
async Task Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var calculations = new[] { Task.Run(() => Calculate1(cts)), Task.Run(() => Calculate2(cts)), Task.Run(() => Calculate3(cts)) };

    try
    {
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(calculations);
        Console.WriteLine($"Got this result: {completedTask.Result?.Value}. Task which yielded result first: {completedTask.Result?.TaskName}");
                
        //cts.Cancel();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae){
    Console.WriteLine($"Catched an aggregate exception: " + ae.ToString());
        
    }

}

public async Task<Result> Calculate1(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 3)
            {
                throw new DivideByZeroException("Oh noes from Calculate1! Got a div zero err!");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Attempting to calculate the result inside Calculate1. Attempt #{i} ..");
            await Task.Delay(500, cts.Token);
        }
    } catch (System.OperationCanceledException oce){
        Console.WriteLine($"Calculate1() was canceled. {oce.Message}");
    }
    return await Task.FromResult(new Result { Value = 43, TaskName = "Calculate1" });
}

public async Task<Result> Calculate2(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    try
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Attempting to calculate the result inside Calculate1. Attempt #{j} ..");
            await Task.Delay(600, cts.Token);
        }
    }
    catch (System.OperationCanceledException oce)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Calculate2() was canceled. {oce.Message}");
    }
    return await Task.FromResult(new Result { Value = 44, TaskName = "Calculate2" });
}

public async Task<Result> Calculate3(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    await Task.Delay(800, cts.Token);
    return await Task.FromResult(new Result { Value = 42, TaskName = "Calculate3" });
}

public class Result
{
    public object Value;
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
}
```

There are details into this, but running the sample code gave this output:

```
Attempting to calculate the result inside Calculate1. Attempt #1 ..
Attempting to calculate the result inside Calculate1. Attempt #1 ..
Attempting to calculate the result inside Calculate1. Attempt #2 ..
Attempting to calculate the result inside Calculate1. Attempt #2 ..
Got this result: 42. Task which yielded result first: Calculate3
Calculate2() was canceled. A task was canceled.
Calculate1() was canceled. A task was canceled.
```

You could also let your calculations catch event more or any exceptions themselves instead of letting the errors be catched at higher levels in the code. Note that we here use a Result object with both a Value and a TaskName. We could though look at the Id property of completedTask also to output the index of the fastest task like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Got this result: {completedTask.Result?.Value}. Task index which yielded result first: {calculations.TakeWhile(c => c.Id != completedTask.Id).Count()}");
```

Here we find the calculation which succeeded fastest and the index of the task array.

```
Got this result: 42. Task index which yielded result first: 2
```

Since you get index 2, this means that the third calculation returned first by control of Task.WhenAny

You could also consider using Task.ContinueWith and  TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted also. This has the benefit that Calculate1 will be run, and Calculate2 will only run if Calculate1 faulted. While Task.WhenAny will kick off all tasks and give the first calculation. However, we also use CancellationTokenSource here so we can cancel the other calculations as quickly as we got an answer.

Since your question is kind of open, I bet there will be a lot of other different suggestions here, but using Task is one 'strategy' in identifying which Task completed first and there are a lot of more into this.